# ARToolkit - call to OpenGL ES API with no current context

Tags: android, opengl-es, android-intent, augmented-reality, artoolkit

Currently I'm working on ARSimpleNativeCars in ARToolKit4Android that release on 2012-03-09. Before running the ARSimpleNativeCarsActivity class, I add in another menu class. In that class I start a new intent in a button:
     Intent myIntent = new Intent(Assignment_Main.this, ARSimpleNativeCarsActivity.class);
     startActivity(myIntent);

The camera view is working fine but the model does not appear. When I check my logcat, there is an error, call to OpenGL ES API with no current context.

But if I run the ARSimpleNativeCarsActivity class directly then is working.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check the update to ARToolKit for Android released 2012-12-06, which includes a fix for an issue which might be affecting you. The release notes say:

> A problem with texture loading when using Wavefront .obj models in the Android examples has been fixed. Now, a new function glmReadOBJ2
>   delays loading and submission of the textures until the model is ready
>   to be drawn. Previously, texture loading was performed when the model
>   was loaded, and typically no OpenGL context would be valid at that
>   point.

In other words, initialising the native code portion in the application, including model loading, was failing because textures were being loaded without a valid OpenGL context. The code now implements lazy loading of textures. You might be seeing the same problem.